# Create view using postgres function

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I'm trying to build a parametrized view using a postgres function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaB.testFunc(p INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (SELECT * FROM schemaZ.mainTable WHERE id=p)
```

The problem is always the same:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"

Any idea on what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the columns of the "return table", this is either done using

```
returns table(col_1 integer, col_2 text, ...)
```

In your case you are returning only rows of one table, so it's easier to use

```
returns setof maintable
```

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) the function body needs to be enclosed in single quotes, or using [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

As stored functions can be written in many different languages in Postgres, you also need to specify a language - in this case `language sql` is suitable.

So putting all that together, you need:

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaB.testFunc(p_id INT)
  RETURNS setof  schemaZ.mainTable
AS
$$
 SELECT * 
 FROM schemaZ.mainTable 
 WHERE id = p_id
$$
language sql;
```

A `return` statement is not required for `language sql` functions.

Comment: would it be possible to return 2 or more selects from diferent tables based on the p_id parameter? For example: if p_id = 1 returns the select from schemaZ.mainTable, if p_id = 2 then it returns the select from schemaz.tableSecondary1, etc ?