# How to return diferent table data based on an ID passed to an SQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-schema, dynamic-sql, sql-function

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273632/create-view-using-postgres-function/61273690#61273690) I would like to know if it is possible to return different table data based on an ID passed to the function.
Something like (pseudocode):

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaB.testFunc(p_id INT, select_param INT)
  RETURNS setof  schemaZ.Table_1
AS
$$
CASE
    WHEN select_param = 1 THEN SELECT * FROM schemaZ.Table_1 WHERE id = p_id
    WHEN select_param = 2 THEN SELECT * FROM schemaZ.Table_2 WHERE id = p_id
END;
$$
language sql;
```

`Table_1` and `Table_2` share no same columns and that invalidates the above `RETURNS` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **generally impossible with SQL functions**. Even with a polymorphic return type, the actual return type must be determined at call time. But all statements in an SQL function are planned before the function is executed. So you'd always end up with an error message for one of the `SELECT` statements returning data that doesn't fit the return type.

The same ***can* be done with dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function** - with some trickery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_demo(_tabletype anyelement, _id int)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = $1', pg_typeof(_tabletype))
   USING  _id;
END
$func$;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT * FROM f_demo(null::schemaZ.Table_1, 1);
```

The "trick" is to cast a `null` value to the desired table type, thereby defining the return type *and* choosing from which table to select. **Detailed explanation:**

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Take this as proof of concept. Typically, there are better (safer, less confusing, more performant) solutions ...

Related:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Comment: Ok, so I'll use separate funcions for each table. The SETOF part needs to match the returning rows format, right? Having many joins in that select could make that part Tricky or is it "doable"?

Comment: @Eunito: Can't say, not enough information. Try, and if you encounter problems you might ask a new question about the problem you encountered.